# search data in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Can someone help me and tell me what's wrong here?

```
String date = "Samstag, 30.7.2011";
        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);     
        String load = "SELECT db_scheine FROM ZahlenUndDatum where db_datum= "+date+"";

       Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery(load, null);
       String test = c.toString();
       Log.d("output", test);
```

I would like to search for the date in the database and then return the value of the record from db_scheine.

Answer (score 2):

try adding moveToFirst()

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery(load, null);
c.moveToFirst();
String test = c.toString();
```

The rawQuery() method, will create a cursor, which is initially placed before the first row. So you can do something like this:

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery(load, null);
while(c.moveToNext()) {
// do stuff
}
```

Without skipping the first row :)

UPDATE:
Your date is giving problems as well, im guessing the db_datum field is a string, enclose the string in quotes like so:

```
String load = "SELECT db_scheine FROM ZahlenUndDatum WHERE db_datum= '"+date+"'";
```

Comment: Still crash with this error: 08-01 16:47:57.180: INFO/Database(958): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error

Comment: still keep it in, it will never write anything if you dont go to the first row. Its null at that time.

Comment: you have a sql error then, its your date. I updated the answer

Comment: I would recommend using c.moveToFirst() as the predicate of an if statement, that way you can have an else block to handle cases when the SQL returns nothing in a controlled manner.